# Need to decode the AJAX response from php into 2 urls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, image-gallery

I am getting an ajax response from a PHP. I want to decode the response , and get the 3 URL's

The code is HTML/JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".goButton").click(function() {
   var dir =  $(this).attr("id");

   var imId = $(".theImage").attr("id");
   $.ajax({
      url: "viewnew.php",
      data: {
         current_image: imId,
         direction    : dir
      },
      success: function(ret) {
          alert(ret);
         $(".theImage").attr("src", ret);


         if ('prev' == dir) {
            imId ++;
         } else {
            imId --;
         }
         $("#theImage").attr("id", imId);
      }
   });

});
});
</script>


<body>
<img id="416" class="theImage" src="" />
  <a href="#null" class="goButton" id="next">Next</a>
</body>
```

And the PHP file is

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM picture ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rec = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC );

echo $rec['pic_location'];
```

I want to get the next 3 image also so that i can show that these 2 images will come up in full screen when the next button is clicked. One will Appear as a full size and other as a thumbnail. How do i decode the response from the Ajax ?

Comment: One thing that has nothing to do with your question, dont use MySql's Random function. If you have many rows and the query is used very often your server will go down (believe me, I once made that mistake.. once). Use Php to choose random numbers and then make the query out of it

Comment: Use JSON to pass multiple values from your ajax script..

Comment: @MichaelRoewinTan -So i should then alert ("image1's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ ); and for image 2 `alert ("image2's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ );`` Is this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".goButton").click(function() {
   var dir =  $(this).attr("id");

   var imId = $(".theImage").attr("id");
   $.ajax({
      url: "viewnew.php",
      data: {
         current_image: imId,
         direction    : dir
      },
      success: function(ret) {
          var arr = eval(ret);
         alert("first: " + arr[0] + ", second: " + arr[1]);


         if ('prev' == dir) {
            imId ++;
         } else {
            imId --;
         }
         $("#theImage").attr("id", imId);
      }
   });

});
});
```

Not tested, but I think it should work. (This code assumes PHP returns the `json_encode()`'ed array)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  on line 3 
, This is the place where the <head> tag is .

Comment: Are you sure you correctly closed the script with `</script>`?

Comment: This happens after i click the next button.

Comment: Are you sure there is no accidentaly lost `<script>` opening tag before there? Because I would think 
`<HTML>  
    <HEAD>  `
Is two lines!

Comment: So the head tag should one line 2.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>`

Comment: 'mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in '

Comment: `$query = 'SELECT * FROM picture LIMIT 5';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rec = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM );

print_r (json_encode($rec[0]));`

Comment: try `$rec = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`.What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from PHP to javascript, use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function on your output, then process with the js callback.

`echo json_encode($rec['pic_location']);`

Comment: how will i decode it  then ? Can you show it please as an alert message ?

Comment: @11684 - So i should then `alert ("image1's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ );`  and for image 2  `alert ("image2's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ );``  

Is this right ?

Comment: @ilanco -So i should then alert ("image1's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ ); and for image 2 `alert ("image2's url is :" + eval(json_variable);+ );`` Is this right ?

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated. In a JSON file you can define an array or an object. If you stored an object, `eval()` of the JSON data would give you an object. If you stored an array, `eval()` would give you an array.

Comment: @11684 - In eiter case how would i get image 1 and image2 's URL ?

Comment: use eval(), and then treat it as an normal array, just as it looked like in PHP.

Comment: @11684 - Is this how its to be done ? `success: function(ret) {
    alert(eval(ret(0)));
    alert(eval(ret));
         $(".theImage").attr("src", ret);
  `